AR(1) model predictions: Are the predictions shifted by one period?
I am estimating AR(1) one step ahead forecasts for the following data using the following code. The AR(1) predictions seem to perform quite well. However, they seem to be shifted by one period in to the future compared to the test data set, as can be seen in the following graph:
(Blue =  True values, Orange = AR(1) predictions)

Now if I would lag the AR(1) forecasts by one period to the past, they would predict the data quite well. Did I do a coding mistake when aligning the data, or is the shift in predictions vs real values due to the nature of the AR(1) model ?
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Given data
data = [
    0.0250477, 0.0251129, 0.0356179, 0.0307251, 0.0308406, 0.0261657, 0.0202818,
    -0.00931811, -0.0220432, -0.0189889, -0.00261438, 0.0192056, 0.0235917, 0.0205837,
    0.00866395, 0.0147383, 0.00198899, 0.0171268, 0.0441156, 0.0226473, 0.0311145,
    0.00671943, 0.0248557, 0.0060732, 0.030977, 0.0050077, 0.0341127, 0.0267606,
    0.0180492, 0.00875824, 0.0247812, 0.0140976, 0.00855742, 0.0136495, 0.01244,
    0.0153917, -0.00566426, -0.00313956, -0.0786389, -0.107904, 0.00624136, 0.0472657,
    0.0483937, 0.0304634, 0.0378904, 0.0125033, 0.0229479, 0.0131371, -0.00232573,
    0.0105381, -0.00420288, 0.00491876, 0.0110841, 0.00181148, -0.00317995, 0.0130418,
    0.000957056, 0.00511998, 0.0081932, 0.00593517, 0.00472012, 0.0121062, 0.01092,
    0.00214864, -0.00760691, 0.00852348, 0.00707222, -0.00477883, 0.00401124, 0.00676562,
    0.0190308, 0.0138147, 0.00975719, 0.0101072, 0.0170982, 0.00335135, 0.00595302,
    0.00953274, -0.00623326, -0.00880799, -0.000888626, 0.00423146, -0.00450886, -0.0395503,
    -0.105516, 0.120913, 0.0439542, 0.0209713, 0.0111634, -0.00319514, 0.0330441,
    -0.00239651, 0.00381834, 0.0112099, -0.0192566, -0.00970307, -0.00110293, -0.00331245,
    0.00270514
]

# Create a pandas Series
y = pd.Series(data)

# Calculate the split index (70% training, 30% testing)
split_index = int(len(y) * 0.7)

# Split the data
y_train = y[:split_index]
y_test = y[split_index:]


# Perform one-step-ahead forecasting
for i in range(len(y_test)):
        print(i, (len(y_train)+i), len(y_test))
        
        y_train_data = y[:len(y_train)+i]

        
        # Estimate AR(1) model
        if len(y_train_data) > 1:
            ar1_model = ARIMA(y_train_data, order=(1, 0, 0))
            ar1_fit = ar1_model.fit()
            ar1_preds[i] = ar1_fit.forecast().values[0]
            
forecast_index = range(len(y_train)-1, len(y_train) + len(y_test)-1)
        
# LINEAR: Plotting actual vs predicted values
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
plt.plot(y_test.reset_index(drop=True), label='Actual')
plt.plot(ar1_preds, label='AR(1) Predictions')
plt.title('Actual vs Linear Predicted Values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Presumably the orange curve shows the predictions.  If it were shifted left by one or more time steps, I would be amazed by the predictor, because it would anticipate random changes at or before the times they occurred!

Yes, sorry. The labels are missing, just added.

@george1994: As whuber commented, an AR(1) is always going to be one behind when there is some kind of major shock. This is because it's a function of the previous value.

@mlofton Just to be very clear, and to get to the crux of the matter, any predictor that respects the flow of time in a stochastic process must lag the shocks, major or minor, regardless of the form of the predictor or the model.

@whuber That fully makes sense, I follow your line of argumentation. Extending beyond this question, I raised basically an extension of this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/652072/prediction-of-a-time-series-ar1-vs-ar1-with-exogenous-variables-why-is-the. I would really appreciate if you review.

@whuber: I understand your point. I was just trying to emphasize that it looks clearly lagged at that particular point because the shock was so large. But your point is well taken. Whether the shock is small or large, it's going to take some time before the prediction "reacts".
